# I can't receive notification. I'm using Urban Airship

Tags: android, notifications, urbanairship.com

I'm newbie of developer now I'm develop the application that using the notification I'm use Urban Airship as notification api but I'm encounter some problem this below
1. When the mobile restart and reopen the app can't receive any notification from server.
2. When I clear this app in recent app then it's can't receive notification at all.

I can receive a notification when I only open the application and send the notification at the same time that app opened or when I press home button on android device but not clear recent app

Please help me, How do I receive notification when device power on or when user clear the recent app it's still receive notification like Facebook, Line application

Thank you very much

P.S
This is the partial of my manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
        android:name=".urbanairship.NotificationApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >

...

<activity
            android:name=".urbanairship.ParseDeepLinkActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <!-- Handles any vnd.xxx.xxxx://deeplink URI's -->
                <data
                    android:host="deeplink"
                    android:scheme="vnd.xxx.xxxx" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

<receiver
            android:name=".urbanairship.SampleAirshipReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.urbanairship.push.CHANNEL_UPDATED" />
                <action android:name="com.urbanairship.push.OPENED" />
                <action android:name="com.urbanairship.push.RECEIVED" />
                <action android:name="com.urbanairship.push.DISMISSED" />

                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably calling takeOff outside of the main application class, I am guessing in the main activity. Either use Autopilot described [here](https://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/android/#takeoff), or call takeOff in a custom application class.

Basically Urban Airship SDK needs to be initialized first before it is able to handle a push. That needs to happen in a place that is called when the app is started in the background.